# cannot reproduce error with gradient

Tags: matlab, gradient, numerical-methods

In computing the gradient of variable

```
[dINTRHOdx,dINTrhody,~] = gradient(INTrho, DELTAx, DELTAy, depth);
```

I get an error

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in gradient (line 67)    g(2:n-1,:) = (f(3:n,:)-f(1:n-2,:)) ./
>   (h(3:n) - h(1:n-2));

However, the inputs have coherent dimensions:

```
size(INTrho)
size(DELTAx)
size(DELTAy)
size(depth)
```

> ans =
>
> ```
>     1080         149          52
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>     1080           1
> ```
>
> ans =
>
> 149     1
>
> ans =
>
> ```
> 52     1
> ```

and if I try the following

```
[dx,dy,~]=gradient(rand(5,5,3),1:5,1:5,1:3)
```

(gradient computation of variable with coherent dimensions),
I get no errors.

Note also that I do not have some variable called gradient:

```
which gradient
```

> /Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app/toolbox/matlab/datafun/gradient.m

What could it be the reason of my error?

**EDIT:** ***Partial answer***

If I make the dimensions exactly the same

```
DELTAx=repmat(DELTAx, 1,numel(DELTAy),numel(depth));
DELTAy=repmat(DELTAy, size(DELTAx,1),1,numel(depth));
ddepth=repmat(depth,  size(DELTAx,1),size(DELTAy,2),1);
```

then `gradient` works

```
[dINTRHOdx,dINTrhody,~] = gradient(INTrho, DELTAx, DELTAy, ddepth);
```

But then, why does `[dx,dy,~]=gradient(rand(5,5,3),1:5,1:5,1:3)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the order of your inputs.  The reason `[dx,dy,~]=gradient(rand(5,5,3),1:5,1:5,1:3)` works is because the first two inputs are both of length 5.  A more clear example to see how your input order matters is the following.

```
[dx,dy,~]=gradient(rand(5,6,3),1:6,1:5,1:3)
```

If you change the order of your original inputs to the following it should work.

```
[dINTRHOdx,dINTrhody,~] = gradient(INTrho, DELTAy, DELTAx, depth);
```